# Eclipse Absolute Path Configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have created several projects (with C/C++ files) in Eclipse. I am able to compile on my machine. But when I migrate from my machine to a different PC (different path) the project fails to open (as it is referring to the same path as created on the original machine). Is there any way I can overcome this? I would like the project to work perfectly no matter which path I move the complete project.

Comment: How do you open the project in the eclipse of the second machine? Did you do a `File` -> `Import` -> `Existing project into workspace`?

Comment: When I invoke Eclipse I select the option "Select a WorkSpace". There are several projects(100) in the workspace and I cannot afford to import project by project individually

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new Workspace and then import your projects by using `File` -> `Import` -> `Existing projects into workspace`. Here you have to select the `root directory` of your old workspace.

In the `Projects` list below all your existing projects are shown and you can select all and import them all at once.